# Let $ \omega \in \sigma(P^k).$ If $\omega = \lambda^ k$ then $ \lambda \in \sigma(P).$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, functional-analysis

Denote $ \sigma(P)$ to be the spectrum of a matrix $P.$ Let $ \omega \in \sigma(P^k).$ If $\omega = \lambda^ k$ then show that $ \lambda \in \sigma(P).$

Comment: Are you sure about the wording? Say I take the identity matrix. The spectrum of its square is still $\{1\}$, and yet $-1$ is not an eigenvalue of the original matrix.

Comment: Dylan's right.  Since $(P^k-\lambda^kI)=(A-\lambda I)(A^{k-1}+\lambda A^{k-2} + \ldots + \lambda^{k-1}I)$, you need to know that the determinant of the second piece does not vanish.  In his example, $I^2 - (-1)^2 I = (I+I)(I-I)$.

Comment: This seems highly improbable, since if you're over the complex numbers (say), *every* $\omega\in\sigma(P^k)$ is of the form $\omega=\lambda^k$. And so, I don't think Dylan's example is merely an exception, i.e. I don't think that adding hypotheses on $P$ will yield an interesting result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you're trying to get at the Spectral Mapping Theorem, which says that $\sigma(P^k) = \sigma(P)^k$; equivalently, if $\omega \in \sigma(P^k)$, then **there exists** $\lambda \in \sigma(P)$ with $\lambda^k = \omega$.

To prove this, let $\lambda_1, \dots, \lambda_k$ be the roots (not necessarily distinct) of the polynomial $X^k - \omega$, so that 
$$
X^k - \omega= (X - \lambda_1) \cdots (X - \lambda_k).
$$
Substituting the matrix $P$ into this equation yields 
$$
P^k - \omega I = (P - \lambda_1 I) \cdots (P - \lambda_k I).
$$
Since $\omega \in \sigma(P^k)$, the left-hand side is singular, so at least one of the factors on the right must be singular.  Hence at least one of $\lambda_1, \dots, \lambda_k$ must be in $\sigma(P)$.

Comment: @ Dave, thanks, its exactly what I wanted. I don't know. Should I edit the question (thus the comments will be not valid) or just leave it like this. I think I should just leave it as its!